# How to get item value in v-slot:cell() template of b-table - BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, bootstrap-vue, v-slot

I'm a very new at programming. I'm trying to figure it out how to bind the data to get the link :href work using store, vuex and bootstrap-vue table. I have spent 4 days for this, and now I'm dying. Please help.

books.js(store, vuex)

```
books: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "name 1",
      bookTitle: "book1",
      thumbnail: '../../assets/img/book01.jpeg',
      url: "https://www.google.com",
      regDate: '2019-10'
    },
    {
       id: 2,
      name: "name2",
      bookTitle: "book2",
      thumbnail: "book2",
      url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
      regDate: '2019-10'
    },
```

BookList.vue

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "BookList",
  components: {
  },
  computed: {
    fields() {
      return this.$store.state.fields
    },
    books() {
      return this.$store.state.books
    },
    bookUrl() {
      return this.$store.state.books.url
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      itemFields: this.$store.state.fields,
      items: this.$store.state.books,
      //url: this.$store.state.books.url
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="itemFields" >
      <template v-slot:cell(thumbnail)="items">
          <img src="" alt="image">
      </template>
      <template v-slot:cell(url)="items">
          <b-link :href="bookUrl" >link</b-link>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cell slot contains two properties you're generally interested in:

- `item` (the current row, or, to be exact, the current `item` in `items`)
- `value` (the cell - or, to be exact, the `value` of the current column within the `item`).

Therefore, considering your data, in the case of `v-slot:cell(url)="{ value, item }"`, `value` is equivalent to `item.url`

Any of these would work:

```html
<template v-slot:cell(url)="{ value }">
  <b-link :href="value">link</b-link>
</template>
```

```html
<template v-slot:cell(url)="slot">
  <b-link :href="slot.value">{{ slot.item.bookTitle }}</b-link>
</template>
```

```html
<template v-slot:cell(url)="{ item }">
  <b-link :href="item.url">{{ item.bookTitle }}</b-link>
</template>
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-749qe).

---

Note your question contains a few minor issues which might prevent your code from working (`itemFields` is referenced but not defined, not using proper getters, etc...). For details have a look at the working example.
And read the docs!

Comment: This is amazing. Oh my god. Thank you so much for helping me out. It works! All of them works perfectly. and Thanks for the note. I really do appreciate

Comment: Thanks a lot, the docs are a little bit messy regarding the b-table